# How to add tags to negated words in strings that follow "not", "no" and "never"

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, sentiment-analysis

How do I add the tag `NEG_` to all words that follow `not`, `no` and `never` until the next punctuation mark in a string(used for sentiment analysis)? I assume that regular expressions could be used, but I'm not sure how.

**Input:**
`It was never going to work, he thought. He did not play so well, so he had to practice some more.`

**Desired output:**
`It was never NEG_going NEG_to NEG_work, he thought. He did not NEG_play NEG_so NEG_well, so he had to practice some more.`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you at least show your attempts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make up for Python's `re` regex engine's lack of some Perl abilities, you can use a lambda expression in a `re.sub` function to create a dynamic replacement:

```
import re
string = "It was never going to work, he thought. He did not play so well, so he had to practice some more. Not foobar !"
transformed = re.sub(r'\b(?:not|never|no)\b[\w\s]+[^\w\s]', 
       lambda match: re.sub(r'(\s+)(\w+)', r'\1NEG_\2', match.group(0)), 
       string,
       flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Will print ([demo here](http://ideone.com/ljZWHS))

```
It was never NEG_going NEG_to NEG_work, he thought. He did not NEG_play NEG_so NEG_well, so he had to practice some more. Not NEG_foobar !
```

---

**Explanation**

- The first step is to select the parts of your string you're interested in. This is done with

  ```
  \b(?:not|never|no)\b[\w\s]+[^\w\s]
  ```

  Your negative keyword (`\b` is a word boundary, `(?:...)` a non capturing group), followed by alpahnum and spaces (`\w` is `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, `\s` is all kind of whitespaces), up until something that's neither an alphanum nor a space (acting as punctuation).

  Note that the punctuation is mandatory here, but you could safely remove `[^\w\s]` to match end of string as well.
- Now you're dealing with `never going to work,` kind of strings. Just select the words preceded by spaces with

  ```
  (\s+)(\w+)
  ```

  And replace them with what you want

  ```
  \1NEG_\2
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this with regexp.  Rather I would;

- Split the input on punctuation characters.
- For each fragment do
- Set negation counter to 0
- Split input into words
- For each word
- Add negation counter number of NEG_ to the word. (Or mod 2, or 1 if greater than 0)
- If original word is in {No,Never,Not} increase negation counter by one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in several steps (at least in Python - .NET languages can use a regex engine that has more capabilities):

- First, match a part of a string starting with `not`, `no` or `never`. The regex `\b(?:not?|never)\b([^.,:;!?]+)` would be a good starting point. You might need to add more punctuation characters to that list if they occur in your texts.
- Then, use the match result's group 1 as the target of your second step: Find all words (for example by splitting on whitespace and/or punctuation) and prepend `NEG_` to them.
- Join the string together again and insert the result in your original string in the place of the first regex's match.