# How to add tags to negated words till next punctuation mark in R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, negation

I need some help to figure out how we can simulate in R the solution for adding a tag "NOT_" to every word that follows the negation word till the next punctuation mark.

A solution for Python code can be found here [How to add tags to negated words in strings that follow "not", "no" and "never"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384351/how-to-add-tags-to-negated-words-in-strings-that-follow-not-no-and-never).

I have the following solution for adding the tag "NOT_" to the next word following the negations words: not, never, n't, without, unlikely to

```
str_negate <- function(x) {
  gsub("not ","not NOT_",
            gsub("n't ","n't NOT_",
            gsub("never ","never NOT_",
            gsub("without ","without NOT_",
            gsub("unlikely to ","unlikely to NOT_",x)))))
}

str_negate(FeedbackCommentsVectorProc$Sentences)
```

but I need to adapt it in order to add the tag "NOT_" in every word till the next punctuation mark.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

After trying to figure this out, this is the simplest solution I was able to come up with. **Note:** this will fail if the string has multiple negation words that precede a punctuation mark.

```
library(gsubfn)
str_negate <- function(x) {
   x1 <- gsub("(not|n't|never|without|unlikely to) (\\w+)", '\\1 NOT_\\2', x)
   x2 <- gsubfn('NOT_([^[:punct:]]+)', ~ gsub('(\\w+)', 'NOT_\\1', x), x1)
   x2
}
x <- "It was never going to work, he thought. He did not play so well, so he had to practice some more."
str_negate(x)
## [1] "It was never NOT_going NOT_to NOT_work, he thought. He did not NOT_play NOT_so NOT_well, so he had to practice some more."
```

If having multiple negation words before a punctuation mark would ever be the case....

```
str_negate <- function(x) {
   x1 <- gsub("(not|n't|never|without|unlikely to) \\K", 'NOT_', x, perl=T)
   x2 <- gsubfn('NOT_([a-zA-Z_ ]+)', ~ gsub("\\b(?!(?i:not|n't|never|without|unlikely to))(?=\\w+)", 'NOT_', x, perl=TRUE), x1)
   x2
}
x <- 'It was unlikely to work and it seems like it never was going to end.'
str_negate(x)
## [1] "It was unlikely to NOT_work NOT_and NOT_it NOT_seems NOT_like NOT_it never NOT_was NOT_going NOT_to NOT_end."
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need to add into all words that follow not, never, etc until the next punctuation mark in the sentence. For example, for the input: "It was never going to work, he thought. He did not play so well, so he had to practice some more.", I need the following output: "It was never NOT_going NOT_to NOT_work, he thought. He did not NOT_play NOT_so NOT_well, so he had to practice some more.". Your solution is only adding the tag to the next word and not to all words.

Comment: what does it mean the regular expression \\K you're using in your solution above? I can't find its meaning anywhere.. I was trying to adapt your code to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think that from the list you provided here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html is there any regular expression that will fit to what I need? Many thanks!