# Tag all words between a negative word (like don't or never) and a punctuation as Negative words

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, regex-negation, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to to build a regex match-replace routine which will take all words which occur between a negative word and a punctuation and add a _NEG suffix to them.

> For example:
>
> > **Text**: I don't want to go there: it might be dangerous.
> >     **Output**: I don't want_NEG to_NEG go_NEG there_NEG: it might be dangerous

I have tried almost everything and I have failed. Below is a snapshot of the code I am trying:

```
regex1 = "(never|nothing|nowhere|noone|none|not|havent|hasnt|hadnt|cant|couldnt|shouldnt|wont|wouldnt|dont|doesnt|didnt|isnt|arent|aint|n't)(.*)[.:;!?]"                    
regcom = re.compile(regex1)
def tag(text):
    negative = []
    matching = regcom.findall(text)
    if len(matching)==0:
        return(text)
    matching = list(matching[0])
    matching = matching [0] + " " + matching [1]
    matching = matching .split()
    for neg in matching :
        negative.append(neg)
    for neg in negative:
        text = re.sub(neg + '(?!_NEG)', neg + '_NEG ', text)
    return text
```

Try the above code with **Text** = "I don't want to go there: it might be dangerous"
It works only partially. Also it gives me many logical and syntactical errors if I am applying it to general text.
Any help will be hugely appreciated

Comment: P.S.: I have been referring to Chris Pott's work on Negation handling for Sentiment Analysis... http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net

Comment: May have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384351/how-to-add-tags-to-negated-words-in-strings-that-follow-not-no-and-never?rq=1

Comment: You said "It works only partially."  How about showing us the output.

Comment: Hi Robert, the thing about my code is that it will tag all words which appear in the entire sentence as well as between the negation region I am interested in with _NEG. For example, if the sentence was, "I don't want to eat it: it might cause an allergy", "it" will be tagged with _NEG wherever its present in the sentence. That's not what I want. I want "it" to be tagged with _NEG only if it's present in the negation region (between a negative word and a punctuation). Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
def tag_words(sentence):
    import re
    # up to punctuation as in punct, put tags for words
    # following a negative word
    # find punctuation in the sentence
    punct = re.findall(r'[.:;!?]',sentence)[0]
    # create word set from sentence
    wordSet = { x for x in re.split("[.:;!?, ]",sentence) if x }
    keywordSet = {"don't","never", "nothing", "nowhere", "noone", "none", "not",
                  "hasn't","hadn't","can't","couldn't","shouldn't","won't",
                  "wouldn't","don't","doesn't","didn't","isn't","aren't","ain't"}
    # find negative words in sentence
    neg_words = wordSet & keywordSet
    if neg_words:
        for word in neg_words:
            start_to_w = sentence[:sentence.find(word)+len(word)]
            # put tags to words after the negative word
            w_to_punct =  re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z\']+)\b',r'\1_NEG',
                               sentence[sentence.find(word)+len(word):sentence.find(punct)])
            punct_to_end = sentence[sentence.find(punct):]
            print(start_to_w + w_to_punct + punct_to_end)
    else:
        print("no negative words found ...")


s1 = "I don't want to go there: it might be dangerous"
tag_words(s1)
# I don't want_NEG to_NEG go_NEG there_NEG: it might be dangerous
s2 = "I want never to go there: it might be dangerous"
tag_words(s2)
# I want never to_NEG go_NEG there_NEG: it might be dangerous
tag_words(s3)
s3 = "I couldn't to go there! it might be dangerous"
# I couldn't to_NEG go_NEG there_NEG! it might be dangerous
```